# pointer shows up as (null)

Tags: c, linux, pointers, gcc

My app runs fine on system A but segfaults on system B.

System A (Hyper-V vm)

- Linux System_A 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Tue May 13 16:33:32 UTC 2014 i686 GNU/Linux
- gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)
- Filesystem: ext3

System B (Raspberry Pi)

- Linux System_B 3.12.28+ #712 PREEMPT Tue Sep 16 15:49:13 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
- gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1)
- Filesystem: tried with ext3 and ext4

The app's purpose is to keep track of changes made in a directory using `inotify`. It saves meta data to a (to be created if it doesn't exist) log file. But, on System B it doesn't even get that far.

When I run the program to monitor changes to a directory it crashes when it tries to work out which file is being modified.

I have done some digging and it seems that a filename pointer (that I use as a temporary filename holder while I work out whether the file is of interest) is not properly set.

The variable is initially set using

```
char *filename;
```

I don't use the variable in any other way until I fill it with a filename that is being modified.

When I then copy the event filename (the file that is being modified) to a temporary variable it segfaults:

```
strcpy(filename,event->name);
```

Now, when I add some

```
printf("ignoring %s \n", event->name);
printf("filename = %s \n", filename);
```

..before the strcpy so I can see what's going on I see:

On System A

```
ignoring .testfile.swp
filename = Hd¤¿Xè|·ðc¤¿ÿÿÿÿô¿~·®
```

On System B

```
ignoring .testfile.swp
filename = (null)
Segmentation fault
```

The only difference I can see at this stage is that the variable 'filename' is perhaps not initialzed properly. But maybe that is of no concern and perhaps I am looking in the wrong direction.

Questions:

- do I need to 'prepare' the pointer before I use `strcpy` or should this just work?
- is there a limitation between the two `gcc` versions that causes this? I just compile with `gcc worklog.c -o worklog`
- is there perhaps a way to get more informative debugging output when the segfault occurs?

Comment: You need to allocate memory with `malloc()` and set `filename` to point to it. Otherwise, where is `strcpy()` supposed to copy to?

Comment: `char *filename;` doesn't assign any storage; `strcpy(filename, …)` copies data over random pointers, or maybe a null pointer if you're lucky.  Undefined behaviour — bad, to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Any idea why it doesn't break on System_A perhaps? Maybe incorrect, but I've been using it like this without problems for years..

Comment: Run your program through Valgrind.  It can help spotting memory errors.

Comment: You were just incredibly lucky. Undefined behavior means anything can happen.

Comment: Isn't that amazing.. falling through the cracks for such a long time, heheh.. Ok, I will add the malloc bit and see how we go. Great help everyone! :-)

Comment: @Barmar Both your and Debasish solutions seem to work perfectly. I'm inclined to accept the quickest answer (Debasish), but Barmar was first in his comments to point to the right direction and his code is also smaller. Would not including the sizeof and strlen bits make much difference here?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`. It's just a style choice whether you include it or not.

Comment: I'd give a slight edge to Barmar's answer. Omitting `sizeof(char)` is simpler, and leaving out the `(char *)` cast is a best practice in C. Also, his answer was first, no?

Comment: @John Kugelman I really appreciate the excellent feedback here people. Great stuff.. I will leave the thread open for a day or so for any further comments that may help gain support for Debasish answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can copy to `filename`, you need to allocate space:

```
filename = malloc(strlen(event->name)+1); // +1 for the null terminator
strcpy(filename, event->name);
```

Comment: Although both answers solve my specific problem I have accepted this answer because of it being slightly shorter and easier to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate buffer space first as in:

```
filename = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(event->name)+1));
strcpy(filename,event->name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your superfast answer, it definitely solves my particular issue.